# How to get python-magic to identify file type of docx correctly instaead of as application/zip?

Tags: python, excel, xml, ms-word, mime-types

I'm developing a website which allows users to submit files and then I use Python to detect the file type. I learned that all MS Office files are actually zip files but how do I determine that it contains a single MS Word(or other MS Office) file? I tried getting the first few bytes with:

```
validator = magic.Magic(uncompress=True, mime=True)
mime_type = validator.from_buffer(open(file_path, 'rb').read(1000))
```

But no matter how many bytes I read it still returns application/zip.

I'm now trying:

```
import zipfile
myzip = zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, 'r')
'[Content_Types].xml' in myzip.namelist()
```

to test if the zip file contains an xml file, which returns True.

I also ran `myzip.namelist()` which returned:

```
['word/numbering.xml', 'word/settings.xml', 'word/fontTable.xml', 'word/styles.xml', 'word/document.xml', 'word/_rels/document.xml.rels', '_rels/.rels', 'word/theme/theme1.xml', '[Content_Types].xml']
```

which returned all the files in the zip file but I'm not sure what next to do to get the mime.

To be sure I ran the same command with a xlsx file as file_path which returned:

```
['[Content_Types].xml', '_rels/.rels', 'xl/workbook.xml', 'xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels', 'xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml', 'xl/theme/theme1.xml', 'xl/styles.xml', 'xl/sharedStrings.xml', 'docProps/core.xml', 'docProps/app.xml']
```

as a test to ensure the results are different.

I want to ensure that a single file is submitted and to be able to detect the file type but I'm not sure what to do next to ensure I get the correct MIME type.

Comment: '.xlsx' or '.docx' are a bunch if zipped XML files, ergo they are zipped files with a different extension name as shown. Of course the magic number will be the same as a zipped file, it has to be. Therefore checking what is inside the zipped file will help you as the answer below covers.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify MS Office files like `docx` within a ZIP container by checking specific XML paths in the Zip file that are unique to the MS Office file type.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html

```py
import zipfile

def get_office_mime_type(file_path):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, 'r') as myzip:
        namelist = myzip.namelist()
        if 'word/document.xml' in namelist:
            return 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
        elif 'xl/workbook.xml' in namelist:
            return 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
        # Add more conditions for other MS Office file types if needed
    return 'application/zip'  # default if not an MS Office file

mime_type = get_office_mime_type(file_path)
```